# What is the trivial module functor?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

In Weibel's book on homological algebra, he mentions the trivial **G**-Module on page 160. By this, does he mean the the functor $\mathcal{F}: \text{G-Mod} \to \text{G-Mod}$ by making $G$ act trivially on each object?

Comment: My copy (which may be a different edition or printing to yours) says: "Considering an abelian group as a trivial $G$-module provides an exact functor from $Ab$ to $G-mod$", which seems pretty clear.

Comment: So, the functor takes an Abelian group $A$, gives it the trivial action of $G$ (each element of $G$ acts on $A$ as identity), and this is the assignment $Ab\to {}_GMod$.